# UIScrollView crashes app when touched

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, crash

I am running into a very annoying problem: I am creating an UIScrollView that containes an UIView that contains some buttons. The UIView with buttons work fine. But the UIScrollView, no matter what I do with it, when touched, crashes. It doesn't make any difference it's empty or not. It keeps crashing.

I am very lost and don't know what else to try.
Thanks very much.

In the viewController.h

```
@interface tagstestViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
        UIScrollView            *scrollViewContainer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scrollViewContainer;
```

In the viewController.m:

```
    UIScrollView *scv       =   [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 200)];
    scv.backgroundColor     =   [UIColor blackColor];
    scv.autoresizingMask    =   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;   
    scv.bounces             =   YES;
    scv.scrollEnabled       =   YES;
    scv.clipsToBounds       =   YES;
    scv.delegate            =   self;

    [self setScrollViewContainer:scv];

    [scv release];

    [self.view addSubview:scrollViewContainer];
```

Comment: You need to think about your question's tags jordi - nothing in this question identifies the platform you're on, for a start

Comment: What error message do you get with crash?

Comment: actually nothing. which makes it more annoying. 

(and sorry for the lack of tags. I will pay more attention next time. thanks Vladimir for editing it)

Comment: Are you implementing any of the methods of `UIScrollViewDelegate` in your view controller? If so, do any of those methods have side effects? Have you tried setting breakpoints at reasonable places to trace execution? What kind of crash are you getting? EXEC_BAD_ACCESS? objc_msgSend? an unhandled exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you releasing your viewController right after you add its view into the view hierarachy? Because if you do that, I noticed that even though the application keeps running fine, if you use "scv.delegate = self", it will crash when it tries to deliver the delegated messages to the viewController.